# Why am i getting XMLHttpRequest error status 0 from google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets

I have an app on google app engine. I just had to update it and add some extra functionality. I wrote a servlet for that. And sending request using jQuery.ajax(), which i am using before in my whole app. Request goes to servlet and performs all operations i want to do. And creating a json string for response. There is no exception in servlet. But i get XMLHttpRequest error status 0 at client side. I tried a lot to searched it and went through documentation but couldn't solve it. Do anybody knows that why is it happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you hosting your app and requesting a response from the same domain? What browser are you using to test?

Comment: yes. and i am using mozilla firefox for testing

Comment: Are you using an absolute or relative path to access your resources?

Comment: Possible cross-domain security issue??

Answer (score 0):

It might be a cross domain issue at google app engine, some of the google site will ignore the cross domain HTTP OPTION request generated by XMLHttpRequest.

The XMLHttpRequest POST/PUT will first send a HTTP OPTIONS request header to the resource on the other domain, in order to determine whether the actual request is safe to send. But some of the google site always reply "404 Not Found" for this request. And you will receive http_request.status = 0 at your callback function.

You can use a Chrome browser and press "F12" to use developer tool to monitor the HTTP OPTIONS issue.